# Drupal 8: Create a custom panel (tab) on the configuration page

Tags: drupal-8

Tell me how can I create a custom panel using a custom module (and yml files) on the configuration page and put an arbitrary link there?

[Example panel (tab)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZL5Xe.png)

Answer (score 0):

Did it:

```
# Register a tab on the configuration page
name_shower.admin_config_panel:
  route_name: name_shower.admin_config_panel
  title: 'My Custom Panel'
  parent: system.admin_config
  description: 'It is my custom panel'
  weight: -5
  url: internal: #

# Add link 
name_shower.admin_index:
  title: 'Name shower settings'
  description: 'Settigns for module "Name shower"'
  parent: name_shower.admin_config_panel
  route_name: name_shower.admin_index
  weight: 0
  url: internal:/admin/config/name_shower
```